# How to get column reorder working in datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have created a datagrid with a little customization.
The last column header is made up of the usual textblock plus a stackpanel under it with rotated text.

In order to make it look better I made the first 6 columns 25 in height with vertical alignment at the bottom, otherwise they would have stretched to the top.

[image]

My second image shows that I can reorder the last column.
[image]

However I can not reorder any of the first six.

In the next pics (Left) I removed the vertical alignment altogether making it sit in the center by default, (Right) I set the vertical alignment to the Top.
[image]

As you can see there must be another level of component, you cannot just alter the DataGridColumnHeader style and expect it to be reordered via dragging.

**Questions:**

- What do I need to add to my style to bring the dragability down to sit with the lower DataGridColumnHeaders at the bottom, as in the first image?
- How do I find this constraint? Can I iterate through the elements of the headers listing them out somehow?
- And lastly the transparent floating dragged image of the column is aligned to the top I would like that brought down to sit at the bottom with the actual header labels, how to do?

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="DGTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="250" Width="500">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid Name="gridUsers" Background="Transparent">
        <DockPanel Background="Transparent">
            <DataGrid Background="Transparent" CanUserReorderColumns="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" CanUserReorder="True" IsReadOnly="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=User_ID}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Username" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Username}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Title" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Job_Title}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Department}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company" CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource ColumnHeaderStyle}" Binding="{Binding Path=Company}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="False" >
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Label Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="25" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" >
                                    Access
                                </Label>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent" CanVerticallyScroll="False" CanHorizontallyScroll="False">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Read" Width="80" Margin="20,1,0,1" >
                                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                          <RotateTransform Angle="-60"/>
                                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Write" Width="80" Margin="-15,1,0,1" >
                                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                          <RotateTransform Angle="-60"/>
                                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="Administrator" Width="80" Margin="-15,1,0,1" >
                                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                          <RotateTransform Angle="-60"/>
                                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to fulfill your requirement with the following changes. Change the ColumnHeaderStyle as given below. I just given raw style of column headers with the following changes. Change that as per your application needs.

```
  <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    </Style>

 <Style x:Key="ColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                    <Grid>
                    <Border Background="Gray" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="1">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                    </Border>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_LeftHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <Thumb.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Thumb.Style>
                    </Thumb>
                    <Thumb x:Name="PART_RightHeaderGripper" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Thumb.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                <Setter Property="Width" Value="8"/>
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="SizeWE"/>
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </Thumb.Style>
                    </Thumb>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Also set the DragIndicatorStyle of all columns as given below.

```
 <Style x:Key="DragIndicatorStyle" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="75"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-25,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>                   
    </Style>
```

Comment: this is fantastic! Is there any way to make the drag box 25 as well, not sure if I have made that very clear. When you drag there is a full height box that appears, can this be shortened or disappear altogether?

Comment: How did you learn about these components? Or rather where/how can I find this if I need to?

Comment: At the moment I can't find the way to reduce the height of the insertion adorner that appear while dragging the header. But with my changes the dragged column header size can be reduced. Learn about Styling and Templates concept, which is common to all wpf components.

Comment: Just noticed that the left and right gripper for resizing gets wiped out by the above.

Comment: Edited the ColumnHeaderStyle in the above answer to include resize grippers.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is to do with making the Header only 25 high removes the correct drag/drop targets which is why it doesn't work correctly.

Putting a custom Header on each row seems to give the behaviour you desire. In this case as it is being wrapped in a Grid, there is a control filling the entire space so the drag/drop can work correctly. (The styling of the header could be moved to a Style I think rather than repeating it on each column). I think there must be a better way than giving the stack panel a size of 90 but I can't find a better way at the moment.

```
<DataGridTextColumn CanUserReorder="True" CanUserSort="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Company}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="25"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Height="90"  Grid.Row="0"/>
            <TextBlock Height="25" Grid.Row="1">Access</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>                        
</DataGridTextColumn>
```